# Laravel, page has to load and then shows the image

Tags: html, laravel

I need your help.

In my web page, after page load, the image has to wait some seconds and then it is shown. 
But this is not user-friendly. How can I handle this situation?

I don't want to use the loader icon because it delays the page so much.

Comment: reduce image size :)

Comment: @DitoKhelaia I can not. It is a blog page.

Comment: you can add validation rule img size shoud be less than 2 mb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do multiple things:

1. Load image independently so that it doesn't affect page load time.
2. Style a placeholder container so that everything looks good with or without an image and the layout doesn't jump around when the image is loaded.
3. Cache the image.
4. Scale image down on server. If it's uploaded by users, you can save both, the original and a scaled down version. Display the scaled down version by default and load the original only if the user clicks on it or something.
5. Invest in better hardware to reduce network latency :)

Also, not sure what icons you use but they shouldn't affect page load time by much. Try [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/animating-icons)